# Beatiful soup python - downloading images from google search in their full size

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, google-search

I'm working on a script that downloads only the first image from google search. I've already managed to get it working with this code:

```
def download_image(query):
    url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}&tbm=isch" 

    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    img_tag = soup.find("img", {"class": "yWs4tf"})

    if img_tag is not None:
        img_link = img_tag.get("src")
        print(query + ' - Downloading image: ' + img_link)  

        os.mkdir(IMAGE_SAVE_PATH)
        
        response = requests.get(img_link)
        image_bytes = BytesIO(response.content)
        img = Image.open(image_bytes)
        img.save(IMAGE_SAVE_PATH + query + '.png')
    else:
        print("Couldn't find image for: " + query)
```

My problem is that it downloads images only in the size it is displayed in google search, but not in their original size. I tried changing html size attributes of these images and then downloading it, but it didn't work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

a. you can try to resize image after downloading it by
`image = image.resize(X,Y)`

b. if *a* is not for you than you need to understand that result of image searches on search engines shows you thumbnail of images not the actual images. What we see are thumbnails and original location is somewhere else and if you want to download them in original size then you need to go to that site and download from there.

Comment: Of course, but how do I navigate to the original location using bs4?

Answer (score 0):

You're extracting the url shown for the image, which is the thumbnail, not the full image of course. Unfortunately this url is a bit harder to get because it doesn't get loaded when viewing the image, only after clicking on it.

It is equally hard to simulate this because it's loaded via javascript as far as I'm aware. You could rewrite the whole thing to use a web driver, like Selenium to simulate user interaction with the images, being able to load them.

I'll include a little script that searches for 'clowns' and downloads the first 10 images it found, in its full resolution through Selenium in a headless setting and places them in a directory called 'images'

To test it you'll have to first do a `pip install selenium Pillow requests webdriver_manager`.

```py
import os
import time
from io import BytesIO
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from PIL import Image
import requests


# Directory where images are to be saved
IMAGE_SAVE_PATH = os.path.join('.', 'images')

# Create directory if not exist
os.makedirs(IMAGE_SAVE_PATH, exist_ok=True)


def setup_driver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

    return driver


def click_consent_if_exists(driver):
    try:
        consent_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/form[2]/div/div/button/span'))
        )
        consent_button.click()
    except:
        print("No consent form found, proceeding...")


def download_image(query, num_images):
    url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}&tbm=isch"

    driver = setup_driver()

    try:
        driver.get(url)
        click_consent_if_exists(driver)

        action_chains = ActionChains(driver)

        for i in range(num_images):
            try:
                image = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.rg_i"))
                )[i]

                action_chains.move_to_element(image).click().perform()

                img_tag = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#Sva75c > div.DyeYj > div > div.dFMRD > div.pxAole > div.tvh9oe.BIB1wf > c-wiz > div > div > div > div.n4hgof > div.MAtCL.PUxBg > a > img.r48jcc.pT0Scc.iPVvYb'))
                )

                img_link = img_tag.get_attribute("src")

                if img_link is not None and img_link.startswith('http'):
                    response = requests.get(img_link)
                    image_bytes = BytesIO(response.content)
                    img = Image.open(image_bytes)
                    img_filename = f"{os.path.join(IMAGE_SAVE_PATH, query.replace(' ', '_'))}_{i}.png"
                    img.save(img_filename)
                    print(f"{query} - Downloaded image: {i}")
                else:
                    print(f"Couldn't download image for: {query}. Error: Link is None or not http")

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error occurred: {str(e)}")

    finally:
        driver.quit()

download_image('clowns', 10)
```

Note: The XPATH and CSS Selectors are what worked for me at the moment, however it is possible it needs some adjustment depending on if the pages load differently for you.